# Why is the function never reached?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

So this is probably quite simple but I can't find the solution or what is happening. I am trying to call the sendRecording from the event handler inside the handleRecorder function. But the sendRecording  is never reached:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

declare var MediaRecorder: any;

const sendRecording = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log('3');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({});
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/recording', body, config);
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
  }
};

const handleRecorder = () => {
  console.log('1');
  sendRecording();
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();

    const audioChunks: any[] = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
      console.log('2');
      sendRecording();
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }, 3000);
  });
};

const Recorder = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className='btn' onClick={handleRecorder}>
        <i className='fa fa-microphone' title='Record' />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recorder;
```

When I click the button, the console prints:
1
2
But never the 3

It actually happens the same when I call the sendRecording function from the beginning of the handleRecorder function.

I'm still learning, it must be something simple that I have not understood, but it is taking me ages to solve this.

Comment: You have a typo `const sendRecording = () => async dispatch => {` should say `const sendRecording = async dispatch => {`. Otherwise, `sendRecord` will return but not invoke the function which contains `console.log('3')`

Comment: To add a bit on what junvar said, your current setup of `() => async dispatch { ...` is literally assigning sendRecording to a function that returns an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done was a closure function, which is a function inside a function
you can find out more about that here: https://javascript.info/closure.

The way you have defined the function `sendRecording` is incorrect for this usage.

It should be something like this:

```
const sendRecording = async (dispatch) => { 
...
}
```

not sure why you have an argument called dispatch, especially since it's not used.
you can now execute this function by simply calling

```
sendRecording();
```

Answer (score 1):

why you sending in the dispatch params?
try removing it to :

```
const sendRecording = async () => {
  console.log('3');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({});
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/recording', body, config);
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
  }
};
```

Comment: the `stopRecording` function would still need the `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to all of you!
I don't know what I did there ^^"

The dispatch was there because I was using it but I removed some code before posting it here but forgot to remove the dispatch.

It works perfectly anyway, thank you.